# FCM iOS - Remove Older Push Notifcation Tiles when a new Push Notiifcation is recieved

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM in Xamarin Forms and is working as expected. But I want to remove all the notifications from the notification tray when a new push is received.

I have able to do the same with the Tag key in Android, how to achieve the same on iOS.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can't remove notification comes in notification tray directly. once you tap on notification all notification will remove from list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your AppDelegate: (swift version, not sure about xamarin)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

     UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove notification badges when user opens the app or are you trying to remove it when app is in background?

Comment: When the app is in background , like a notification is recieved and again an notification is recieved so the user should only see the last message recieved.

Comment: Also the IconBadge number is to show the count on the app icon only

Comment: I don't think it's possible to remove a badge without opening an app, you should see if it's possible to remove the badge if user discards the notification from the tray

Comment: I dont want to remove the badge , i want to remove the old  notification in notification tray.

Answer (score 0):

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 //will remove all badge count
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20865632)

Comment: please set badge count as 0 for every time when app become active

Answer (score 0):

Objective C

```
 -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```